# libphp7.so requires version 12.0.0 or later

Tags: php, macos, apache, homebrew

I have a fresh installation of OSX el capitan 10.11.2 and installed php7 using homebrew.Now getting following error

command

```
sudo apachectl -e info -k restart
```

error

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 171 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:
 Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so, 10):
 Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php70/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libphp7.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

I have searched on google but didn't get any specific solution.

Comment: not sure about osx, but `apt-get install libxml2-dev`

Comment: This question needs to be answered...

Comment: Ensure you run `brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv`. It is looking at the system version.

Answer (score 1):

Install libxml2 with brew,

```
brew install libxml2
```

add following line into ~/.bash_profile

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib/:$LIBRARY_PATH
```

The version "2.9.4" can be changed to current

Answer (score -2):

PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS!!! YOUR BEST BET IS TO REINSTALL MAC OS X

<strike>Alright, I just found a way. It is *kinda* hacky, but it works.</strike>

When trying to run `PHP 7`, apache checks for `libxml2.2.dylib` under `/usr/lib`. To check what version it is currently at, you can run `otool -L /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib`.

That will probably output something like this:

```
/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
```

But Apache and PHP want version `12.0.0`, so let's install it through [`homebrew`](//brew.sh).

```
brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv
```

This will install `libxml` to something like `/usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib`. This directory will contain a file called `libxml2.2.dylib`.

If you run `otool -L /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib/libxml2.2.dylib`, it will output:

```
/usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.4.0)
```

So THIS is the version PHP and Apache are looking for. We are going to want to move this file to `/usr/lib`. But not so fast, we already have a file named `libxml2.2.dylib` in that folder so lets just add the `.bak` extension just in case we need it again.

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib.bak
```

Now we can move the file that homebrew installed to this directory.

```
sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.4/lib/libxml2.2.dylib /usr/lib
```

That's it! Now you should be able to run `sudo apachectl -e info -k restart`
 with no errors and `PHP 7` should work correctly.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. Renaming the system libxml2 won't work unless you've disabled System Integrity Protection, and in any event, doing so is likely to break some applications which were distributed with the OS.

Comment: This will break your machine and force you to have to use single user sign-on to repair. BEWARE!! Moving the dylib file violates PAM restrictions and will kill sudo and basically all functionality until you reboot and fix as root.